# Can the Malkavian player use Chaos twice?

Tags: vampire-the-masquerade-vendetta

The Malkavian player has two related cards:

**Chaos**

> You may choose to take 1 or more of your Deployed cards at this Location back into your hand, including this one. For each card you take back, Steal 1 blood from each Rival.

**Madness Network**

> Play all of the cards remaining in your hand at this Location, face up.

Both of these cards are on the "Preparation (sun)" stage.

Can the Malkavian:

1. Use Chaos, taking Chaos + all cards back to their hand but leaving Madness Network.
2. Use Madness Network to deploy all cards again.
3. Use Chaos again, taking all cards back

And thus steal a ton of blood in the process?

Rules seem to support a yes for this question, which is what we went with, but we wondered if there's anything that says no.

> **5.3 Preparation:**
> Players resolve the effects of their Preparation cards.
> Starting with the player with the Ambition
> token and proceeding clockwise, apply
> the effects of each Preparation card you
> have at the current Location. If you have
> more than one card at this Location that
> triggers during this step, **you may decide
> the order** in which you activate them.
> Each card must be entirely resolved
> before activating the next.

> **Contradicting Rules?**
> This is a game about rule-breaking. As such, there will be times where cards seem to
> contradict each other, or this rulebook! Here’s how to resolve these inevitable disputes:
>
> - The text on the cards always prevails over the rulebook.
> - In case of timing issues between cards (i.e., two cards have the same symbol), they are resolved in turn order, starting with the player holding the Ambition token and proceeding clockwise (i.e., card(s) played by the player holding the Ambition token take effect first, then cards by the next player in turn order take effect, etc.).
> - Remember that ties are always resolved in turn order.
> - If a single player has multiple cards that trigger at the same time, they choose the order in which they are resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The publisher clarifies (errata?) this on [this thread on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2570389/cards-placed-during-preparationsunrise-mesmerize-m):

> Chaos (or any other cards) doesn't get activated again once it's played through Madness Network,

> Let's say, for simplicity, each card ability only get activated once regardless of how many times it get played.

and also note that this restriction is "per location" (although that doesn't affect your case). From that same thread:

> Each card activate once PER LOCATION so to speak,